# Open app permission settings

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

Regarding granular permissions on Android M.

In case the user denies twice the request for a permission,

Or that the user mark the "Never ask again".

How can I open/link directly to the app permissions settings?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an `Intent` action in `Settings` for this, even in the MNC docs. `ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS` is probably the closest one.

Answer (score 28):

Let's assume in AndroidManifest.xml you have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<!-- ETC. -->
```

Then, as in the below sample activity, we can check for existing/granted permissions and then send the user to app settings if we're missing any permission:

```
package com.example.permissions.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_APP_SETTINGS = 168;

    private static final String[] requiredPermissions = new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
            /* ETC.. */
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /* All version with SDK_INT < 22 grant permissions on install time. */
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22 && !hasPermissions(requiredPermissions)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please grant all permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            goToSettings();
        }
    }

    private void goToSettings() {
        Intent myAppSettings = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        myAppSettings.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        myAppSettings.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivityForResult(myAppSettings, REQUEST_APP_SETTINGS);
    }

    public boolean hasPermissions(@NonNull String... permissions) {
        for (String permission : permissions)
            if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED != checkSelfPermission(permission))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_APP_SETTINGS) {
            if (hasPermissions(requiredPermissions)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "All permissions granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions not granted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

I just tried it on Nexus 6 / AndroidOS 6 (Marshmallow).

Comment: Just quick addition, This does not work for third party app permission solutions, such as used in the oneplus 2 oxygen os. Settings are managed from a custom settings view in oxygen os.

Comment: @Corne Does it mean the app crashes, or nothing happens?

Comment: @rpattabi you get into a app screen but the permissions in oxygen os are not managed from that screen. Everything still works you just can't change permissions from there thats all.

Comment: Thanks for the addition

Comment: am developing app on lolipop till now.but suddenly plan to update to M please help me when i install app on M showing crashed.am updating with target sdk version and all in build.gradle

Answer (score 20):

use this code for launch your app permission setting page

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
            Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```