# How to open 'App Permissions' page in Settings programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android

I know there is many question about it already. 
But today I found this:

[image]

[image]

My phone is Gallaxy Note 4 and Samsung Gallery app works just as I want
'open App permissions page from Activity!' not setting-detail page.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127116/open-app-permission-settings

Comment: @Daniel Did you find solution to this?

Comment: have you found any solution yet?

Answer (score 8):

Here is a method to open *Settings > Permissions* for your application:

```
public static void openPermissionSettings(Activity activity) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, 
      Uri.parse("package:" + activity.getPackageName()));
  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

You should consider using this when your permission is denied and [`shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Activity activity, String permission)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String)) returns true.

Comment: how to open the permissions screen for a particular application...i have tried this code - Intent intent = new Intent("miui.intent.action.APP_PERM_EDITOR");      intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.miui.securitycenter.permission.AppPermissionsEditor");
            intent.putExtra("extra_package_uid", pInfo.applicationInfo.uid);

Comment: This is opening App Detail Settings page instead of App permissions page, there is still one click away from the destination.