# Android - Setting the app's default "Open supported links" option

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-links

How can I control the default `Open supported links` to either `Ask every time` or `Open in this app` for my Android app? Does it happen in the manifest?

I have two apps that try to accept the same universal link scheme, and the ideal behavior is to have the user decide which app to open when they click on the link. However, it seems that the first app correctly has the `Open supported links` in settings set to `Ask every time`, while the other app has the `Open supported links` as `Open in this app`. Thus, when both apps are installed, only the second one will be opened straight away, whereas the first one won't even be prompted.

The portion that accepts universal links in both of the `AndroidManifest.xml` files are almost identical.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="foo.bar.com" android:pathPrefix="/action/" android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Here the instructions to open the app settings. I still don't know how to get directly to the defaults/links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127116/open-app-permission-settings

Comment: Were you able to solve this? What was the difference in the manifests that made them "almost" identical, but not quite? Was it the `autoVerify` bit?

Comment: Can you please post the working solution if you’ve found one?