# Android open supported links defaults

Tags: android, flutter

The question is duplicate of [Set "Open Supported Links" for Android in React Native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71115227/set-open-supported-links-for-android-in-react-native-app) and [Android - Setting the app's default "Open supported links" option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66647729/android-setting-the-apps-default-open-supported-links-option)

I'm trying to have my app links opening my app by default with asking for the first time and then have to set it as always
Similar to discord when you install it from the app store for the first time it defaults to **Allow to open supported links** while my app which is installed via **flutter run apk** doesn't have that as the default option (default to ask every time), so I would like to know whether this something I can configure in my app settings or it has something to do with downloading from app store

[Discord status just after downloading from app store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q42LB.png)

```
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="serversapplink" android:scheme="serversappdev"/>
            <data android:host="serverapps.page.link" android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:host="dev-servers-app.web.app" android:scheme="https"/>      
            </intent-filter>
```